# How to seperate values from joined table result?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a simple joined table that looks like this.

```
NO   CLASS     NAME    STATUS
 1      1A     JOHN         1
 2      1A     SARA         1
 3      1A     LYOD         1
 4      1B     JOHN         1
 5      1B     SHIN         1
```

I use `textbox` to display the `CLASS` and a `TEXTAREA` to display the `NAME`. The output of `CLASS 1A` should like this:

```
Class : 1A
Name  : JOHN, SARA, LYOD
```

How to do it using the joined table only (not multiple query)?

THis is how I loop the result:

```
$query  = $this->xxx->yyy($class_name); //JOINED RESULT

    $data = array(
        'titlepage'     => APP_TITLEPAGE,            
        'record'        => $query, //This is the result that is sent to the view
        'complete'      => 'true',
        'loadmethod'    => 'add',
        'contentpage'   => 'test_page/detail'   
    );

    $this->load->view('shared/master_app', $data);
```

Comment: You loop through the names and create a string or whatever it is you need.

Comment: I can give you PHP code for this if you need...?

Comment: sure. I'm open to any solution.

Comment: can you give me array you got in $query .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so your query array is something like this:

```
$query = [
    ['NO' => 1, 'CLASS' => '1A', 'NAME' => 'JOHN', 'STATUS' => '1'],
    ['NO' => 2, 'CLASS' => '1A', 'NAME' => 'SARA', 'STATUS' => '1'],
    ['NO' => 3, 'CLASS' => '1A', 'NAME' => 'LYOD', 'STATUS' => '1'],
    ['NO' => 4, 'CLASS' => '1B', 'NAME' => 'JOHN', 'STATUS' => '1'],
];
```

You may make a function that arrange it or group it
lets name it groupResults($query)

```
function groupResults($query) {
    $result = [];
    foreach($query as $queryItem) {
        $result[$queryItem['CLASS']][] = $queryItem['NAME'];
    }
    return $result;
}
```

now result is looks like this:

```
$result = [
    '1A' => ['JOHN', 'SARA', 'LYOD'],
    '1B' => ['JOHN']
]
```

this is a snapshot of what I got:

[image]

so now you can use it like this

```
$query  = $this->xxx->yyy($class_name); //JOINED RESULT
$data = array(
    'titlepage'     => APP_TITLEPAGE,            
    'record'        => groupResults($query), //This is the result that is sent to the view
    'complete'      => 'true',
    'loadmethod'    => 'add',
    'contentpage'   => 'test_page/detail'   
);

$this->load->view('shared/master_app', $data);
```

now in the view you may loop on this array as:

```
foreach($record as $class => $names) {
    echo "<input type='text' value='" . $class . "'>";
    echo "<textarea>" . implode(', ', $names) . "</textarea>";
}
```

Comment: where the `groupResults` is executed? In controller or view. I use CodeIgniter

Comment: @ashura91 you should execute it before sending the data to the view

Comment: also @ashura91, if the data returned as object so use the arrow notation instead of array thing :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add all name in same Class in one column then it can be possible by `GROUP_CONCAT()` mysql function.

adjust your query with GROUP_CONCAT. For an example see below

```
SELECT CLASS, GROUP_CONCAT(NAME) 
FROM  table_name 
GROUP BY CLASS;
```

It will Output like this

```
1A JOHN,SARA,LYOD
2A JOHN,SHIN
```

You also can put custom separator between names using GROUP_COCAT separator

```
  SELECT CLASS, GROUP_CONCAT(NAME SEPARATOR ' -- ') 
    FROM  table_name 
    GROUP BY CLASS;
```

For reference [MySql GROUP_CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: no, I want to leave the query alone. I want to do it in the PHP. Because I use the `JOINED TABLE` for another purpose beside displaying `CLASS` and `NAME`